# remove space between bottom nav bar and bottom of screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I created my own bottom app bar following a tutorial. However, there is a white space between the bottom nav bar and the bottom of the screen. I colored this space in white to show it. How can I make my container the actual nav bar and hide that space?
This is happening on all of my screens in the app regardless if they begin with a scaffold, column, container etc.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class bottomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const bottomAppBar({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Container(
        color: Color(0xFF313131).withOpacity(0.7),
        height: 50,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/discover');
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/mybookings');
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.hello,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/user');
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to unwrap your build body from SafeArea Widget, from where this bottom app bar is being called.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you use the scaffold propery from the materail app. But, never wrap the widget with the scaffold widget.

> After wraping the widget in scaffold use the `bottomNavigationBar` property to put your `BottomAppBar`. Then every thing will work perfect.

Thank you.

**Code (Your updated code)**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class bottomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const bottomAppBar({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Container(
          color: Color(0xFF313131).withOpacity(0.7),
          height: 50,
          width: double.maxFinite,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/discover');
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/mybookings');
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.ac_unit,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/user');
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output Screen**

[image]

Comment: I tried this method, even copy pasting the code you wrote but the content of my screen is gone afterwards and just shows a white screen like in your screenshot.
The spacing also still remains

Comment: It doesn't work for me :(